# Unable to insert products into ms access db

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

Im receiving a number of different errors when trying to insert products into my access DB. Such as Malformed String: ). User lacks privilege or object cant be found. Different errors when i try and insert different products.

tried re creating the db, debugging to the hilt.

public boolean addNewProduct(Product product)
    {

```
    String Make = "";
    String Model = "";
    String Type = "";
    String Genre = "";
    String AttConsole = "";
    String Desc = "";

    if(product.getClass().getName().equals("Models.Game"))
    {
         Game game = (Game)product;
         Genre = String.valueOf(game.getGenre());
         AttConsole = String.valueOf(game.getAttributedConsole());
         Desc = String.valueOf(game.getDescription());
    }
    else if(product.getClass().getName().equals("Models.Console"))
    {
         Console console = (Console)product;
         Make = String.valueOf(console.getMake());
         Model = String.valueOf(console.getModel());
         Desc = String.valueOf(console.getDescription());
    }
    else
    {
        Peripheral peripheral = (Peripheral)product;
        Type = String.valueOf(peripheral.getType());
        Desc = String.valueOf(peripheral.getDescription());
    }

     try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Price, StockLevel, Description, Genre, AttributedConsole, Make, Model, Type) VALUES "
                + "('" + product.getProductName() + "','" + product.getPrice() + "','" + product.getStocklevel() 
                + "','" +  Desc + "','" + Genre + "','" + AttConsole + 
                "','"  + Make + "','" + Model + "'," + Type + ")");
        //sql statement to add new products to database
        conn.close();
        return true;
    }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {
          String message = ex.getMessage();    
          return false;
     }

}
```

ex = (net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException) net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: )
ex = (net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException) net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 user lacks privilege or object not found: RAZOR

Comment: The `Type` is not quoted in SQL, which can be the reason. Don't build SQL by string concatenation. As you already found is error-prone and opens SQL injection attack vector. Use `PreparedStatement` with parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Struggling with that at the moment. Could you give me an example? Cheers

Comment: there is a tutorial on prepared statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string concatenation to insert column *values* into SQL command text. Search for "SQL Injection" or "Little Bobby Tables" for more information on why that is a "Bad Thing"™.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement` to run a *parameterized query*, e.g.,

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO tableName (intColumn, textColumn) VALUES (?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setInt(1, 12345);
    ps.setString(2, "my text value");
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```